# jQuery .extend() and .merge() giving odd results inside Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, merge, jquery-autocomplete, extend

I've tried using merge and extend to combine arrays inside an Autocomplete ajax option - the jQuery Autocomplete UI widget.  They both work, but neither as they are supposed to.  In the code below using extend(), only the contents of objectB display in the dropdown box. If I reverse the order of the arguments, only objectA displays, i.e., the second argument displays but not the combination with the first. When I change it to merge( objectA, objectB ), only the contents of objectA display. With merge(), only the first argument displays, but not the combination of both. How do I get the combined contents of both arrays to display? (Eventually, objectB will be completely different, but I'm just trying to get the concept working.)

```
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: geonamesData,
                success: function( data )
                {   var objectA=null;
                    var objectB=null;
                    var objectC=null;
                    response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item )
                    { objectA={
                                label: item.name + (item.adminName2 ? ", " + item.adminName2 : "") + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                                value: item.name + (item.adminName2 ? ", " + item.adminName2 : "") + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : ""),
                                name: item.name   
                              };
                      objectB={
                                label: item.name + (item.adminName2 ? ", " + item.adminName2 : ""),
                                value: item.name + (item.adminName2 ? ", " + item.adminName2 : ""),
                                name: item.name
                               };
                      objectC=$.extend({},objectA, objectB);
                      return objectC;
                    }));
                }
            });
```

Comment: "How do I get the combined contents of both arrays to display?"  The problem, as I see it, is that you *have* no arrays.  ;-)

Comment: @ Ben Blank  Its not hard to know more javascript than me since I just started 2 months ago, but you did not even tell me why it is not an array. Next time, be helpful. pst solved my problem - see below. See if you can become a helpful problem solver for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.extend` deals with properties - it merges properties leftwards. That is, any properties appearing in "righter" argument will override all same-named properties appearing in any "lefter" argument. (The result is a single object, which is the same object as the first parameter: the first input object is *mutated*).

`$.merge` can be thought of a "concat" -- but see note -- as it concatenates two arrays (or array-like things) together. (The result is a single array, which is the same object as the first parameter: the first input array is *mutated*.)

If you want a collection of items, return a collection of the items (normally an array).

E.g. `return [objectA, objectB]`.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks, that's it.  I didn't know returning a collection was possible. All my books show return of one object. Also, thanks for the short jQuery lesson. Its helpful.

Comment: This would have saved me the past hour if I would have found it sooner.  What I found was $.extend changes the properties of an object (but not the total number of elements) and $.merge will actually change the length of the object.  Say for example, you want to ADD a button to a .dialog(), you would use $.merge but if you wanted to change the text/function of a button, you would use $.extend.